# Why has A4 Borderless format disappeared for HP 6500?

Tags: printing, hp

2 months ago I've bought HP Officejet 6500 E709n printer. At the beginning there was a "A4 Borderless" page format and I could print images without white borders. Now this page format has disappeared and I cannot remember making any changes apart from installing recent 10.10 updates.

Any ideas why? How can I get it back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK as far as I can see there has been 1 update of hplip since the release of maverick you can check this by opening synaptic package manager in the administration menu. Do a search for hplip it will be at the top of the results page. If you right click on the package you can select properties in the properties dialog there is a versions tab which shows earlier versions of the package. You can then select "force version" from the "package" menu one word of warning forcing an older version can cause problems so I would back-up your system before making this change in case you have to do a clean reinstall also make a note of the package names of files which will be changed by the forcing of an older version.
[image]

ps this bug may be of interest to you
["hpcups" driver of HPLIP has broken margins](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/405116)

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this way of checking out versions and updates. Downgrading hplip helped. Actually hplip gets removed on downgrade and hplib-cups and hplib-data are used.

Comment: I declared victory too early - hplip is broken after downgrade and printing doesn't work at all. Printer reports some problem with filter.

Comment: ok, I got it working. My downgrade was not complete. I had to downgrade following packages: hplip hplip-cups hplip-data libhpmud0

Comment: Congratulations ps. if everything is fine you may want to lock the version using the same package menu.