# How to prevent updating of a specific package?

Tags: updates, package-management

Because of [bug #693758](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/693758) I'd like to prevent `apt-get upgrade` and Update Manager from updating the "libgtk2.0-0" package.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: @hhlp: But this question is asking about a package that was never installed.

Comment: @George Edison - There is also package holding, which allows you to not update the package. so Holding a package basically means you're telling the package manager to keep the current version no matter what. This is useful if more recent version of a currently working program breaks after an update. (you can't hold a package that was never installed also see my question is the same).... i tested that right now - see he said `disable packages from the auto-update`

Comment: Since this question was asked before we moved from `apt-get` to `apt`, it's worth noting that `apt-mark hold packagename` is still the standard solution for this. Trying `apt hold` will just complain with `E: Invalid operation hold`

Answer (score 827, accepted):

## Holding

There are different ways of holding back packages: with `dpkg`, `apt`, `dselect`, `aptitude` or Synaptic.

### dpkg

Put a package on hold:

```
echo "<package-name> hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Remove the hold:

```
echo "<package-name> install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Display the status of all your packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Display the status of a single package:

```
dpkg --get-selections <package-name>
```

Show all packages on hold:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "\<hold$"
```

### apt

Hold a package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

Remove the hold:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```

Show all packages on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

### dselect

With dselect, enter the [S]elect screen, find the package you wish to hold in its present state and press <kbd>=</kbd> or <kbd>H</kbd>. The changes will take effect immediately after exiting the [S]elect screen.

---

The following approaches are limited in that locking/holding a package within aptitude or synaptic doesn't affect apt-get/apt.

### aptitude

Hold a package:

```
sudo aptitude hold <package-name>
```

Remove the hold:

```
sudo aptitude unhold <package-name>
```

### Locking with Synaptic Package Manager

Go to **Synaptic Package Manager** (System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager).

Click the search button and type the package name.

When you find the package, select it and go to the **Package** menu and select **Lock Version**.

[image: Synaptic menu]

That package will now not show in the update manager and will not be updated.

Comment: This also works to prevent a package from being installed. When installing `devscripts`, a lot packaged are pulled as Recommended packages. As I don't need a mailserver (postfix), I could disable the installation of it by running `echo postfix hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections` before running `sudo apt-get install devscripts`. This hold action persists only for this installation, after the installation the selections are reset.

Comment: Also worth pointing out, package holds do break upgrades and patches sometimes by creating a situation where there is no legal solution apt can calculate to a dependency. If package foo has a ==  < or <= dependency on libbar, then apt will refuse to upgrade libbar as well as foo. Over time, these cascading dependencies may grow to block a large number of updates, including important security updates. You'll need to either remove the hold and let the upgrade happen, or rebuild the packages you are holding against newer versions of its dependencies if this happens.

Comment: Just a note: `apt-mark` doesn't support `hold` in version 0.7.25 (Ubuntu Lucid)

Comment: How can this be achieve in muon (kubuntu's update manager)?. Thanks in advance. Also, the package was downloaded (older version of chromium) so it isn't appearing in the muon GUI (at least what I see), it is appearing on the update manager though.

Comment: I can confirm that `sudo apt-mark hold/unhold` currently works in Ubuntu **16.04** (Xenial Xerus). I held some obsolete packages and then executed `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in order to see if they would be upgraded, but the held packages were not upgraded. By the way, you can hold/unhold several packages at once. Example: `sudo apt-mark hold thunar thunar-dbg thunar-data libthunarx-2-0 libthunarx-2-dev`. Nice!

Comment: If I could bump you up by 2 points I would.  Your advice for how to use Synaptic to tell apt not to upgrade packages X, Y, Z was incredibly helpful!  I have not tested your other methods for blacklisting certain packages b/c the Synaptic version worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: Could someone here define the difference between **holding** and **locking**?

Comment: Also, a bit of elaboration as to what **apt, aptitude, dpkg**, etc are, what they do, how they differ and whether for preventing a given package from updating all/either/some of these commands need to be run would not go amiss. The current answer is too terse and presupposes too much background knowledge (imho). -- For a bit of relevant/important background reading and commentary, read, for instance, this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package#comment102573_86229

Comment: How about packages installed from snap market?

Comment: Using apt-mark hold is preventing me from upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04:
```
hin@xps:~$ update-manager -d
Gtk-Message: 22:22:12.308: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```
However, I have run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: just a note: at least nowadays the hold-flags from `dpkg`, `apt-mark`, `apt` and `aptitude` are honored by each other. and even Synaptic kind of recognizes them: the held packages are still shown as upgradeable (if there is something to upgrade to of course) and you can mark them manually to upgrade, but when hitting the button "Mark All Upgrades" they are left out. **but** locking via Synaptic seems to still be "Synaptic-exclusive".

Comment: As even more packages are nowadays recommending all kind of crap, it's good to know about `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends the-package-name`. That way you don't need to apply any hold tricks to avoid installing unneeded packages.

Comment: Is it worth promoting the `apt-mark hold` option to the top of this answer?  As far as I can tell, that's the recommended method now.

Comment: The synaptic method failed to hold for me.

Comment: With sudo apt-mark hold, how can you apply it to all packages?

Answer (score 53):

I was looking for the same thing and after a lot of research I found that using the following syntax you can forbid one specific version but allow the next update:

```
Package: compiz-plugins-main
Pin: version 1:0.9.7.0~bzr19-0ubuntu10.1
Pin-Priority: -1
```

This goes into the `/etc/apt/preferences` file.

Comment: This is a much better way than preventing updates indefinitely

Comment: With this method, I think, chances are bigger to prevent ubuntu 'adware' like ubuntu one or the amazon icon from being reinstalled with the next release upgrade...

Comment: This method also prevents **Aptitude** from reporting that a package is "Upgradable" (assuming an older version is being used than is available in the repo's)

Comment: @Digger but once a newer version appears, I mean newer than the one pinned to -1, aptitude will once again report the package as upgradeable.

Comment: After using this, you can check with *apt list --upgradable*. If you need to prevent multiple packages, see https://superuser.com/a/678411/316381 or just created multiple files in the folder */etc/apt/preferences.d/*

Answer (score 45):

To put a package "foo" on hold:

```
echo "foo hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

In your case we are going to put wine on hold:

```
sudo -i
echo "wine hold" | dpkg --set-selections
```

To remove the hold:

```
sudo -i
echo "wine install" | dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Also note that while a package is on hold, you *can* install a specific version via `apt-get install wine=1.2.3`. Being on hold prevents `apt-get (dist-)upgrade` from changing it.

Comment: @rcoup If you have an old version on hold, and then you manually upgrade to a new version without removing the hold as you describe, will the old version be kept in the cache so that you can go back to it?

Comment: @cxrodgers the local cache (typically `/var/cache/apt/archives`) is independent of holds & upgrades & stuff, so all the versions you've downloaded will be there until you run `apt-get [auto]clean`

Answer (score 23):

Install `synaptic` using `sudo apt-get install synaptic`.

Run using `gksudo synaptic` and on the search box locate the package you want to lock, ie: `gedit`

[image]

From the package menu select **Lock version**:

[image]

And that is all, the version currently installed at the time of the lock will stay installed even during upgrades.

Comment: Please look at "Lock version is not as clever as it sounds. It's supposed to do what it says on the tin, lock the version... But it only locks it within Synaptic. Anything else that does package upgrades (read: Update Manager, apt-get, aptitude, etc) ignores this. This is probably buggy behaviour so I would expect this to be fixed in time." from http://askubuntu.com/questions/9607/what-does-lock-version-do. What is the current state? If something is locked in Synaptic, will other package managers "honor" the lock?

Comment: vasa1: As of version 0.75.13, still no :( Same problem with aptitude.

Comment: As of 0.84.3 (Jan '21) it still does not use apt-mark

Answer (score 16):

Preventing a package from being installed is called "package holding" and it is very simple to do:

```
echo package_name hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

...where *package_name* is the name of the package you want to prevent from installation.

**Note:** the above command assumes root privileges. In other words, you will probably need to type `sudo su` before running it.

Comment: Perfect [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction%20to%20Holding%20Packages) was the answer. Thank you.

Comment: `s/sudo su/sudo -s/g` (or `sudo -i`). (`-i` will give a login shell, `-s` will not).

Answer (score 13):

Since some time `apt-get` is replaced by `apt`, so for example I want to prevent Firefox from updating to version above 56, because a lot of add-ons, like ["Tab Groups"](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-groups-panorama/) don't work any more with the new Firefox 57 (see "WebExtensions Update").

It is possible to hold more than one packages with one command and use wildcards.

### Prevent Firefox from updating

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox firefox-locale-*
```

If you should deside to unhold them later, that would be the command:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold firefox firefox-locale-*
```

Answer (score 6):

Everything you ever wanted to know about "holding" and "pinning" packages to specific versions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

Answer (score 4):

I synaptic you can freeze the version of a specific package I'm not a 100% sure as to whether this will amend apt-get but it will definately stop update manager.

To freeze a package select it in synaptic then open the package menu and select freeze version.

Hope this helps

edit: This [question 16668](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16668/why-has-a4-borderless-format-disappeared-for-hp-6500/16678#16678) deals with a similar situation

Answer (score 4):

Adding details to @[soger](https://askubuntu.com/users/177306/soger)'s comments relative to Ubuntu 16.04.

Ubuntu 16.04 does not have an existing /etc/apt/preferences file by default. If you don't have one currently, just create a new file and populate it with a stanza as @soger describes above to exclude the given package and its dependencies from updates.

Afterwards, run `apt update` and you're GTG. :0)

For example, I have an Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS server with embedded Intel video card and an NVidia card. The NVidia card is the only one used. The server also uses CUDA drivers. I had a problem where `apt` kept insisting

> va-driver-all

(Intel drivers) required an update, but it could not determine which version to install. This was driving me nuts, and I didn't need the Intel drivers anyway. I entered this text into the preferences file and flushed apt, problem solved.

```
Package: va-driver-all
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Answer (score 3):

See bugs [#75332](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/75332), [#158981](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/158981) and [#72806](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/72806).

The summary is that hold at apt-get / aptitude level is not triggering hold status in dpkg (see bug 72806 especially) and update-manager reads status from dpkg.

workaround is run as root:
`echo "package hold" | dpkg --set-selections`

Answer (score 3):

Just because it was not mentioned here, the KDE tool Muon has an option similar to Synaptic's:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use on aptitude the "specific override", like this:

```
aptitude reinstall ~i oracle-java8-jre:
```

This is a one time only use of (not stored for future reinstalls), keep specific override, to reinstall all packages in your system but not oracle-java8-jre.

If you use a keep specific override, the package will momentarily be in a state of keep and aptitude will not try to install it.

A very good thing if you think your system was compromised some how as you can reinstall everything in just one punch card.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Synaptic installed you can select the package and use the menu Package -> Lock Version to prevent it being updated.

You can install Synaptic with sudo apt-get install synaptic. I personally find it more useful than the Software Center... then again, I'm fairly old school. :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep a package at the currently-installed version and prevent it from being automatically upgraded, you can add an [APT preference fragment](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html) to `/etc/apt/preferences.d` like this:

```
Package: vim
Pin: release a=now
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally one might want to hold back *all* the packages currently installed.  Here's how.

First save the current state, so you can undo:

```
dpkg --get-selections > current_selections.txt
```

Then, to hold back all the packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed -r "s/\tinstall/hold/" |dpkg --set-selections
```

Finally, when you want to revert back to the previous state:

```
dpkg --set-selections < current_selections.txt
```

One use case for this might be when creating a VM or Amazon AMI snapshot to migrate from a QA to production environment.